# How do I enable command line remote access to a Windows Server 2008 machine?

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-access

I have a Windows Server 2008 machine. 99% of the time, all I need to do to administer it is run command line commands such as `hg fetch`. I would like to move from Remote Desktop to just opening a (secure) command-line session.

Some googling found [this article](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/install-SSH-Server-Windows-Server-2008.html) which only lists third-party ssh servers for Windows. I want the most "legit" option. What do you recommend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install Powershell 2.0

In powershell on the server enter:

> set-executionpolicy remotesigned -force
>
> enable-psremoting -force

Then from a remote machine (that has powershell enabled) initiate a remote connection:

> etsn -cred username -comp targetname

If you are on the same domain and have proper authorization you can skip the '-cred username' part, but I've found if you're crossing domains with non-mutual trust then it is necessary to use credentials of the remote domain.

Also if you want to just issue one command you can do something like...

> icm targetname {$host }

The above should be enough to get you started down the magical world of powershell remoting.

Comment: note: on the client, I had to install powershell 2.0 for server 2003 x64 since there isn't an x64 version of Windows XP

Comment: I don't see how this relates to SSH - or the question is very badly written ?!

Answer (score 4):

We have used WinSSHD for years.  It is rock-solid.

http://www.bitvise.com/winsshd

Comment: +1 for WinSSHD. It may be third party but it integrates well and is simple to setup. That said it sounds as though you don't need any of the extra features a full-blown ssh daemon provides, so the powershell option might be best.

Comment: My favorite part about WinSSHD is the FTP window in the Tunnelier client PLUS the ability to run WinSSHD on any port you want, for security through obscurity.

Answer (score 2):

Forget SSH and learn how to use PowerShell remotely. PowerShell supports secure remote execution per default in the newest version.

Comment: But is it able to tunnel like putty.exe ,  winsshd, or ssh can do?